# How do you conditionally add condtions to a Firestore query in with the JavaScript SDK or React Native Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

For the sake of handeling infinite scroll, I created a function that add conditions to the query according to the desired behavior:

```js
  const queryDocs = async (behavior: string = 'start', limit: number = 25) => {
    let augmentedQuery: Query<DocumentData> | CollectionReference<DocumentData> = query
    try {
      if (behavior === 'start' || behavior === 'limited') {
        augmentedQuery = augmentedQuery.limit(limit)
      }
      if (behavior === 'next' && lastItem) {
        augmentedQuery = augmentedQuery.limit(limit).startAfter(lastItem)
      }
      const snapshot = await augmentedQuery.get()
      if (behavior === 'start' || behavior === 'next') {
        setLastItem(snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1])
      }
      return snapshot
    } catch (error) {
      throw functionError(error, 'queryDocs', [behavior, limit], 'useCollection')
    }
  }
```

I get the following error:

> on queryData("start",1) in module useCollection: Attempted to assign to readonly property.

Can we take take a previous query and add a .where or .limit?

Is there a solution to handle conditional queries?

Thanks

***Edit:*** As Doug stated in the discussion, it is perfectly possible to chain queries like this. The error comes from another source. This code was into a shared package that was recompiled from TypeScript to ES6 and then used in React Native. After merging all the code into the React Native directory the error changed. I had a request to create a composite index with the link to do so, what is quite straightforward.

Comment: You can definitely chain queries. That's how the API works.  What line of code here does that error refer to?  What is the readonly property being referred to?

Comment: Thanks a lot Doug, it is very nice to have you on StackOverflow. I understand that the problem is not with chaining. I previously had all my custom hooks and state management in a separated npm package for reuse between the mobile and web app. I made a test and fused the src directories of the packages directly into the React Native src directory to have something monolithic. Now the error message has changed. "The query requires an index", wich is much more clear. I think I will keep duplicating the code until the packages are stable enough to avoid this source of strangeness... Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Xiiryo please, if you have updated error messages now, consider updating your question description as well. In case you have find out a solution for your problem, consider adding it here as an answer.